# Select first non-missing values over multiple rows in SQL (Updated with example)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table of customer names and biographical information.  However, the table can have more than 1 row per customer, but all customers are still grouped by the same ID.  So for example... customer 12345 below has 3 total rows.  Some rows will have a first name, and some won't.  Ditto for lastname, birthdate, etc.  For example, here is all the information we have for customer 12345 in a single table:

```
customerid | priority | firstname | lastname | birthdate | state |
12345      | 1        | null      | Doe      | 11051983  | null  |
12345      | 2        | John      | Does     | null      | TX    |
12345      | 3        | null      | null     | null      | Texas |
```

And I need to roll customer 12345's rows up into 1 row, and it has to have as much biographical information as possible.  How do I have SQL go through and find the first non-missing values (firstname, lastname, birthday, etc) and include those in customer 12345's final row?  So the final result should look like this:

```
customerid | firstname | lastname | birthdate | state |
12345      | John      | Doe      | 11051983  | TX    |
```

Since the customer info is over multiple rows, I don't believe I can use the Coalesce function.  Any other ideas?

This has to be done in SQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "first non missing values" - with respect to what order? if there are 2 rows with the birthday, do you care which one's used?

Comment: I added an example above to show how to handle this.  Each record would have a priority.  And the first non-null value from the highest priority would be what is shown in the table.

Comment: @GeorgeRodman, why **max** does not work on this?

Comment: Because I don't necessarily want the highest value of birthday, or the longest string for lastname.  I want the first non-null value from the highest priority record. 

Imagine that the 3rd record above had a birthdate record of 11051984.  While that record may be greater, it doesn't come from the highest priority source... which is what I want.  So MAX would pull the birthday from the 3rd record, when I want the value from the first record since it's a higher priority.

Comment: @GeorgeRodman I modified my answer from MAX to SUBQUERIES, it does what you need now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this *merge* can be done using **SUBQUERIES**

INPUT

```
12345   NULL    NULL    NULL        Texas
12345   NULL    Does    11051983    NULL
12345   John    Doe     NULL        TX
12346   NULL    NULL    NULL        Texas
12346   NULL    Last    1245678     NULL
12346   First   Last2   NULL        TX
```

INPUT (Query)

```
declare @tbl table(customerid int,firstname varchar(100),lastname varchar(100),birthdate varchar(100),state varchar(100))
insert into @tbl
select 12345,null,'Does','11051983',null union
select 12345,'John','Doe',null,'TX' union
select 12345,null,null,null,'Texas' union
select 12346,null,'Last','1245678',null union
select 12346,'First','Last2',null,'TX' union
select 12346,null,null,null,'Texas'
```

Main Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 CustomerID,
 (SELECT TOP 1 firstname FROM @tbl tbl2 WHERE tbl2.customerid=tbl.customerid AND firstname IS NOT NULL ORDER BY priority) FirstName 
,(SELECT TOP 1 lastname FROM @tbl tbl2 WHERE tbl2.customerid=tbl.customerid AND lastname IS NOT NULL ORDER BY priority) LastName 
,(SELECT TOP 1 birthdate FROM @tbl tbl2 WHERE tbl2.customerid=tbl.customerid AND birthdate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY priority) BirthDate 
,(SELECT TOP 1 state FROM @tbl tbl2 WHERE tbl2.customerid=tbl.customerid AND state IS NOT NULL ORDER BY priority) State 
FROM @tbl tbl
```

RESULT

```
12345   John    Does    11051983    TX
12346   First   Last2   1245678     TX
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(firstname), MAX(lastname), MAX(birthday) FROM customer GROUP BY id
```

Just be careful- if customer #1 has 2 different first names, this will only output to maximum first name.

Answer (score 0):

`For Sql server 2012+`,

```
SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_VALUE(firstname) OVER (
        PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN firstname IS NULL
                    THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END DESC
            ,prioritys
        ) firstname
    ,FIRST_VALUE(lastname) OVER (
        PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN lastname IS NULL
                    THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END DESC
            ,prioritys
        ) lastname
    ,FIRST_VALUE(birthdate) OVER (
        PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN birthdate IS NULL
                    THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END DESC
            ,prioritys
        ) birthdate
    ,FIRST_VALUE(states) OVER (
        PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN states IS NULL
                    THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END DESC
            ,prioritys
        ) states
FROM @t
```